# MySQL c++ not implemented exception

Tags: c++, mysql, notimplementedexception

I'm making a c++ program with MySQL cpp connector, and i'm stuck into:

```
sql::MethodNotImplementedException on 
MySQL_Connection::prepareStatement(const sql::SQLString& sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find nothing... i really don't understand what's happening. Here's the full source of the class that fails:

```
#ifndef __DATABASE_H_
#define __DATABASE_H_

#include <string>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

#define MYSQL_HOSTNAME "localhost"
#define MYSQL_USERNAME "dummy"
#define MYSQL_PASSWORD "password"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

class Database {
public:
    Database();

    static bool login(const string &user, const string &password);

    static Connection *createConnection();
};

#endif
```

And the sources:

```
Connection *Database::createConnection(){
    mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver = mysql::MySQL_Driver::Instance();

    return driver->connect(MYSQL_HOSTNAME, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
}

bool Database::login(const string &user, const string &password){
    bool ret;
    Connection *con = createConnection();
    PreparedStatement *pstmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Players WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?"); // here's where it fails ._.

    pstmt->setString(1, user);
    pstmt->setString(2, password);

    ResultSet *res = pstmt->executeQuery();
    ret = res->next();

    res->close();
    delete(res);
    pstmt->close();
    delete(pstmt);
    con->close();
    delete(con);

    return ret;
}
```

When i compile and link it, i add -lmysqlcppconn as library.

I checked MySQL c++ reference and they say that not all JDBC methods are implemented, but i can't understand why that function is not, if it's a basic one.

Thank you in advance,
Víctor

Comment: I tested it in another computer and it works... might be libraries messed up. will try after a clean linux install.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this afternoon. And now I have found a way to solve it, hope my experience is helpful to you:
I am using ubuntu 10.10 and install mysql connector/c++ by synaptic package manager. And I found the dynamic lib file (libmycppconn.so.xxxx) -- it's size is decades of kilobytes. By accidentally, I get an already compiled lib file at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/1.0.html, it's size is 9 megabytes more or less, which means it may contain a lot more then the previous one. So I decided to remove the synaptic one, and compile the source code, and make / make install it. After I have done this, the libraries work find.
Maybe you can try to compile the source code and install it.

Good Luck,
Xi